# Deleting windows.old from linux live

Tags: linux, linux-mint, windows.old

I have laptop with windows 10 and im trying to delete windows.old folder from linux mint booted in live mode.

I have mounted HDD in -rw mode. 
i have rwxrwxrwx permissions for all sub-directories and files.

but when i run command : *sudo rm -rf windows.old*

I get a lot of outputs for sub-folder:*cannot remove directory is not empty*

Comment: The folder may contain NTFS hardlinks or other that may be problematic for Linux. Can't you boot Windows and do Disk Cleanup?

Comment: Does it tell you the name(s) of the subdirectories that are problematic?   Have you looked in those directories to see what’s there?

Comment: I had a lot of 'problematic' directories in output , so i decided simply delete it from windows in CleanUp tools. Problem is solved.