# Delete symbolic link to c:\ when not being able to access c:\

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, links, mklink

I know how to create and delete symbolic links, but now I have a specific problem. I wanted to create a symbolic link from `c:\mydata` to `d:\mydata`, but forgot the first parameter, so I entered from `c:\`:

```
mklink /D d:\mydata
```

The command created a symbolic link `c:\` to `d:\mydata`. The link is working :-) but now I cannot access my c: drive, because it is mapped to `d:\mydata`. I don't know how to remove this link, can anyone help?

All the answers under the question [How can I delete a symbolic link?](https://superuser.com/questions/167076/how-can-i-delete-a-symbolic-link) do not help me, because:

- I cannot delete c:\ in windows explorer, because there ist no delete option on drive c:
- I cannot open the shell with admin privileges to execute `rmdir c:\` (I'm always getting an error message when clicking right on "shell" and choosing "run as admin" ("...system32\cmd.exe could not be found")

Update:
My system is still running, I can log out and log in, but I'm afraid of rebooting it. It's running since I made the mistake. I can use most of the programs, only a few (like Adobe Reader or opening an admin shell) are not working.

Comment: Can you clarify your situation?  Is your computer basically bricked (i.e., converted into an inoperable lump)?  Or can you still run programs?  Have you logged out and back in, or rebooted?  (If you haven’t, better not try, as you might not be able to get back in.)  But, if you have successfully rebooted, have you tried going into Safe Mode or Recovery Mode? … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: In addition this this, I'd assume now that the PC is bricked. You can insert the hard drive into another device (or boot Linux via USB into the bricked PC) and you should be able to recover all your files and access the C drive.

Comment: @DeanMeehan: The Live Linux USB is a good idea, but do you know whether it will work in this situation?  I’ve read that, while Linux drivers for NTFS can *read* NTFS filesystems well, they have trouble *writing to* them. See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/1422277/354511 "Deleting Windows.old from Linux live") where [harrymc comments](https://superuser.com/q/1422277/354511#comment2146820_1422277) “The folder may contain NTFS hard links or other that may be problematic for Linux.”